# Google Colab, loop through google drive folder, read each CSV file in folder into a datframe, then append dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-ta

I am using Google Colab

I have a folder of CSV files in a google drive directory
`'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Stocks CSVs/Stocks/'`

I want to loop through this folder, read each CSV to a data frame, append this data frame with technical indicators from the `pandas_ta library`, then export the appended data frame back to another google drive folder with the path
`'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Stocks CSVs/Stocks/'`

With the code below I am receiving the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Copy of 138SL.csv'

How can I fix this code, bear in mind I have to use Google Colab as I am using a work laptop and not allowed to download text editors such as VS code.

I have the following code:

```
def TAfunction(data):
  stock_df = pd.read_csv(data)
  CustomStrategy = ta.Strategy(
    name="RSI Strat",
    description = "RSI",
    ta=[
        {"kind":"rsi"},
        {"kind":"bbands", "length": 20},
        {"kind":"macd", "fast": 8, "slow":21},]
)
stock_df.ta.strategy(CustomStrategy)
stock_df.to_csv(data, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
files.download(data) 

test_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Stocks CSVs/UpdatedStocks/'

for file in os.listdir(test_dir):
  if file.endswith(".csv"):
    TA_function(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the full path of the CSV file to `TAfunction()`, because the script does not have the same working directory as where the files are stored. Simply modify the end of your code to join `test_dir` and `file`:

```
test_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Stocks CSVs/UpdatedStocks/'

for file in os.listdir(test_dir):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        TAfunction(test_dir + file)
```